# vue.js dynamically added input v-model does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input, v-model

I googled all day and did not find solution to this problem yet.

I try to build app, where I can insert input with v-model which should be reactive and value of this input must be shown in other *div* element. What I really need is 
to have a code where I would be able to insert this input with v-model to any place in my *HTML* code.

Here is example of my mini app, where everything works well except v-model is not working, because I try to insert it dynamically.

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Here is the code:

```
<template>
<div>
<div id="content"></div>
<button type="button" @click="createNew('typeOne')">Create Type One</button>
<button type="button" @click="createNew('typeTwo')">Create Type Two</button>

<h3 style="color:#000000;" id="formTypeOne0">formTypeOne0</h3>
<h3 style="color:#000000;" id="formTypeOne1">formTypeOne1</h3>
<h3 style="color:#000000;" id="formTypeTwo0">formTypeTwo0</h3>
<h3 style="color:#000000;" id="formTypeTwo1">formTypeTwo1</h3>

</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data () {
  return {
    formTypeOne0: '',
    formTypeOne1: '',
    formTypeTwo0: '',
    formTypeTwo1: '',
    numberTypeOne: 0,
    numberTypeTwo: 0
  }
},
methods:{
  createNew(type) {
    if (type === 'typeOne') {
      var html = '<input type="text" :value="formTypeOne' + this.numberTypeOne + '" v-model="formTypeOne' + this.numberTypeOne + '">'
      document.getElementById('content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html)
      this.numberTypeOne = this.numberTypeOne + 1
    } else if (type === 'typeTwo') {
      var html2 = '<input type="text" :value="formTypeTwo' + this.numberTypeTwo + '" v-model="formTypeTwo' + this.numberTypeTwo + '">'
      document.getElementById('content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html2)
      this.numberTypeTwo = this.numberTypeTwo + 1
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  formTypeOne0: function(val, oldVal) {
    document.getElementById('formTypeOne0').innerHTML = val
  },
  formTypeOne1: function(val, oldVal) {
    document.getElementById('formTypeOne1').innerHTML = val
  },
  formTypeTwo0: function(val, oldVal) {
    document.getElementById('formTypeTwo0').innerHTML = val
  },
  formTypeTwo1: function(val, oldVal) {
    document.getElementById('formTypeTwo1').innerHTML = val
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you used `v-html`?

Comment: instead of v-model? It doesn't make difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, it worked for me. Here is HTML:

```
<template>
<div>
<input id='inputId' type="text" v-model="inputModel">
<button type="button" @click="create()">Create</button>
<div id='division'>  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

and here is method:

```
  create () {
    document.getElementById('division').appendChild(
      document.getElementById('inputId')
    )
  }
```

v-model works for me here.